# print 5 characters that come after a key word

Tags: python, string

I want to make a simple code that takes one piece of text, scans for the keyword and prints the keyword along with the next 5 characters. Note, the keyword can appear more than one time in the text.

```
  string = 'my name is luka 90/91, I live on the second floor'
    keyword = 'luka'

    if key in string:
        print (key + key[0:5])
```

the output should be luka 90\91

Comment: The keyword along with the next five characters would actually be `'luka 90/9'`.

Comment: Would you like to print all the next 5 characters when `keyword` appear ? or only first appearance ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), you can get the index of the matching string:

```
>>> string = 'my name is luka 90/91, I live on the second floor'
>>> keyword = 'luka'
>>> string.find(keyword)
11
```

---

```
>>> i = string.find(keyword)
>>> string[i:i+len(keyword)+5]
'luka 90/9'
>>> string[i:i+len(keyword)+5+1]  # +1 (count space in between)
'luka 90/91'
```

---

**UPDATE** To get all occurrences, you need to find the substring in a loop.

```
string = 'my name is luka 90/91, I live on the second floor luka 12345'
keyword = 'luka'

i = 0
while True:
    i = string.find(keyword, i)  # `i` define from where the find start.
    if i < 0:
        break
    j = i + len(keyword) + 5 + 1
    print(string[i:j])
    i = j
```

---

**UPDATE** solution using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> string = 'my name is luka 90/91, I live on the second floor luka 12345'
>>> keyword = 'luka'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(re.escape(keyword) + '.{5}', string)
['luka 90/9', 'luka 1234']
>>> re.findall(re.escape(keyword) + '.{6}', string)
['luka 90/91', 'luka 12345']
```

- `luka` matches literally. `.{5}` matches any 5 characters following.
- If you want to match characters even though they are less than 5 character. Use `.{1,5}` instead.
- [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) is not necessary for `luka`. It is required if there's special characters that has special meaning in regular expression.

Comment: @JonClements, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: OP also mentioned the substring can appear more than once. You might want to mention `str.index`'s second argument.

Comment: @dabadaba, Thank you for pointing it out. I updated the answer.

Comment: No need for while. Look my answer if it matches his expectation please.

Comment: @TonyTannous, You're right. I updated answer with a regular expression alternative.

Comment: @falsetru yes I see it now. Lost my connection for a while.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

string = 'my name is luka 90/91, I luka onthe second floor'
keyword = 'luka'

i = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(keyword, string)]
K = [[keyword + ' '+ string[len(keyword)+1+j:len(keyword)+j+5+1]] for j in i]
```

Or a better solution:
`L = re.findall(keyword + ' .{5}', string)`

`print(K)`

**OUTPUT:**

```
[['luka 90/91'], ['luka onthe']]
```

`print(L)`

**OUTPUT:**

`['luka 90/91', 'luka onthe']`

I added an additional 1 for the space, and assumed keyword after `keyword` is big enough. Otherwise spaces will occur. If this is unwanted it can be fixed. But such behavior is not defined by you how should be.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just use: `re.findall('luka .{5}', string)` ?

Comment: @JonClements nope. I just gave him a solution I know. I will try this and re-edit if needed. Thanks for note.

Comment: Might want `{,5}` if up to but necessarily 5 or more letters follows the keyword

Comment: or more generally `re.findall(keyword+' .{5}', string)`

Comment: @Copperfield true... I assumed user knows what to change. Changed it my self. Thanks for advice!

Comment: mmm, in your first solution, any reason to put the result in a list of list?

Comment: @Copperfield not really. Could drop the outer `[]`. However I like to save my strings in a list of lists rather than a list of strings. Easier for me to think about it. But that is just me

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'my name is luka 90/91, I live on the second floor. luka means nothing'
keyword = 'luka'
split_array = string.split(keyword)
for x in split_array[1:]: # If keyword is found split array would contain more than one element
   print keyword, x.strip()[:5]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
luka 90/91
luka means
```